# AssertJ/JUnit Failure Trace

Tags: junit, assertj

When program fails to find a component in a test case, a failure trace is shown. It shows attributes of components in the hierarchy. For example:

> [name=null, text='Close', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=false]

I wonder what value of `visible` and `showing` tell us about the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are properties from the `java.awt.Component` class.

The JavaDoc for these properties (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) has the following information:

**visible**:

> Determines whether this component should be visible when its parent is visible.

**showing**:

> Determines whether this component is showing on screen. This means that the component must be visible, and it must be in a container that is visible and showing.